# Running WindNinja CLI in Python

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to run the WindNinja CLIs in Python. I've managed to get the actual WindNinja CLI (WindNinja_cli.exe) to run; however, I am having trouble with the DEM CLI (fetch_dem.exe).

If I run the following lines of code:

```
help = subprocess.run(['path/to/fetch_dem.exe', '--help'], capture_output=True, text=True)
print('Standard Output:', help.stdout)
```

it returns the following text showing the arguments:

```
Standard Output: fetch_dem [--bbox north east south west]
          [--point x y x_buf y_buf]
          [--ogr_ds filename] [--ogr_buf x_buf y_buf]
          [--ogr_lyr lyr_name] [--ogr_where  where_clause]
          [--buf_units miles/kilometers]
          [--out_res res]
          [--src us/world/gmted/lcp] [--fill_no_data]
          [--lcp_srs epsg_code]
          dst_file
```

Now, I run actually run the file using the required arguments. The following is how I'm setting it up:

```
output_path = 'path/to/output/dem.tif'

fetch_dem_args = ['path/to/fetch_dem.exe', f'--bbox {north} {east} {south} {west}', '--src us', output_path]

try:
    result = subprocess.run(fetch_dem_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    if result.returncode == 0:
        print("Fetch DEM process completed successfully.")
    else:
        print("Error - Return Code:", result.returncode)
        print("STDERR:", result.stderr)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print("Error:", e)
```

It returns the output: `Error - Return Code: 1`

Maybe I'm completely missing something obvious, but I'm not sure why it isn't working? The other arguments can either be left as default (e.g., not required to have in the argument setup (`fetch_dem_args`) or are only required if using the `[--point x y x_buf y_buf]` method (not planning on using that method).

Any help is greatly appreciated! For reference, WindNinja is free to download online from the US Forest Service.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass all the arguments and values as separate list elements and let subprocess handle all the commandline parsing and quoting if required.  If you ever need to check, `subprocess.list2cmdline` will show you what will be run.

Assuming these dummy values:

```
output_path = 'path/to/output/dem.tif'
north, east, south, west = 1, 1, 0, 0
```

This is wrong:

```
# Your code
fetch_dem_args = ['path/to/fetch_dem.exe', f'--bbox {north} {east} {south} {west}', '--src us', output_path]

print(subprocess.list2cmdline(fetch_dem_args))
```

Output:

```
path/to/fetch_dem.exe "--bbox 1 1 0 0" "--src us" path/to/output/dem.tif
```

This is correct:

```
# Note all arg values are separate elements
fetch_dem_args = ['path/to/fetch_dem.exe', '--bbox', str(north), str(east), str(south), str(west), '--src', 'us', output_path]

print(subprocess.list2cmdline(fetch_dem_args))
```

Output:

```
path/to/fetch_dem.exe --bbox 1 1 0 0 --src us path/to/output/dem.tif
```

Comment: Running the last line ```print(subprocess.list2cmdline(fetch_dem_args))``` ends up with this error: ```TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not int```

Should the north, south, east, and west variables be converted to strings?

Comment: Ah, gotcha ok. I do wind up with this issue when running it:

```CompletedProcess(args=['path/to/fetch_dem.exe', '--bbox', '40', '-115', '39.6', '-115.4', '--src', 'us', 'path/to/dem.tif'], returncode=4294967295, stdout='', stderr="ERROR 4: `/vsizip/vsicurl/http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM1/Region_01/N39W115.hgt.zip/N39W115.hgt' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name.\nERROR 1: Could not warp image, download failed.\nFailed to open a dataset\n")```

Is this more of a USGS database issue? Or am I not calling it correctly still?

Comment: This is the line I'm using: ```subprocess.run(fetch_dem_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)```, so the same as before

Comment: No, you're calling it right. The [usgs download](https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM1/Region_01/N39W115.hgt.zip) site is down..